# Widget disappears after user logs out and redirects to login screen in MVC4

Tags: janrain

The janrain social widget works great, but when the user logs off and gets redirected to the login screen, the widget disappears.  I even turned caching off, but that made no difference.  Any hacks or tweaks that anyone knows about?  I'm suspecting javascript has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Rudy,
It most likely is a Javascript issue. Are you using the Social Login widget modal or embedded? Do you see any console errors or messages that might point to a cause? Do you have a URL I could take a look?

Comment: I get the same effect using either modal or embedded. The only difference is when I use modal, my hyperlink is present, but doesn't work when you try to click it.  I have a feeling it has something to do with the parentnode.insertBefore routine.  I'll let you know what I see on the console errors.

Comment: Ok, I had an unmatched tag, because I had a div in a <p> tag. I fixed the console error message, but it still just dies upon logout.